# Processing: text won't print only on first activation of mousePressed()

Tags: javascript, text, mouseevent, processing

Backstory: Making a whack-a-mole game in Processing. When you click on a mole it prints *BOINK* above its head and the mole disappears. Running into an issue where on the first click the text won't print. I've triple-checked the location and the fill for the text to no avail.

What confuses me is that if I put a print statement right before the text the print will appear in the console, but if I put any sort of shape before the text it also will not print.

To reiterate, this error is ONLY happening on the first click.

Further testing demonstrated that the same issue occurs with keyPressed, so here is a very short program that demonstrates the error.

```
void setup() {
}

void draw() {
    background(0);
}

void keyPressed() {
    textAlign(CENTER);
    textSize(16);
    fill(255, 255, 0);
    println("test");
    text("Test", width / 2, height / 2); 
}
```

Comment: You'll have much better luck if you post a [mcve] instead of your whole project. You need to [debug your program](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to isolate your problem. Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: I didn't post my whole program, but point taken; shortened it to a non-specific example with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the `draw()` function is called 60 times per second, and each frame you're calling the `background()` function which clears the screen and draws a black background.

Compare that to the `keyPressed()` function, which is only called when the user presses a key. In that, you're drawing some text to the screen.

The problem is, the `draw()` function will then immediately be called and will clear what you just drew.

Instead of using the `keyPressed()` function, you probably want to use the `keyPressed` variable in the `draw()` function, like this:

```
void draw(){
   background(255, 0, 0);

   if(keyPressed){
      background(0, 255, 0);
   }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: I wrote a tutorial on input in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/input).

Comment: If the issue was consistent on every key press, I would agree with you that it is a background() issue; however, as I said, it is only happening on the FIRST press and not any other presses.

Comment: @Tristan Try commenting out the call to `background()` so that you can actually see the text being drawn to the screen. If I do that, I see the text every time, including the first time I press the key.